# Weighted average, ignoring blank cells and avoiding the #DIV/0 cell error before sell has value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

As stated in the title, I am having issues coding for a weighted average (in this example, if the client has bank savings and an annuity, I want the estimated return percentage average to take into consideration there may be 10k @ 1% in the bank, but 120k @ 3% in the annuity. Right now C76 would say the average is 2%; I need it to take the dollars into consideration for a true average rate of return) but also ignoring blank cells and I don't want the #DIV/0 to show up (I would like a blank cell until it has a value).

In the image, you will see that I am trying to accomplish this in C68 (I included the formula, so far, in the screen shot too) and C76. I can seem to get these formulas to play nice and this is a client usage sheet, so I need it to look clean.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Considering the  #DIV/0 you can use your formula like this
`=IF(ISERROR(SUMPRODUCT(C59:C67)/SUMPRODUCT(--(C59:C67<>""))),"",SUMPRODUCT(C59:C67)/SUMPRODUCT(--(C59:C67<>"")))`

or 
`= IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(C59:C67)/SUMPRODUCT(--(C59:C67<>"")),"")`

Another Formula is
`=IFERROR(SUM(C59:C67)/COUNTIF(C59:C67,">0"),"")`
This formula sum all the values and divide by the count of values >0 for sure ignore Blank Cells for the Average